# Error while reading web table into R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to read in a table from this website "http://saws.org/Your_Water/aquifer/Water_Stats/index.cfm?search=Yes" but I get an error "Error: failed to load HTTP resource"  this is my code:

```
library("XML")url <- "http://saws.org/Your_Water/aquifer/Water_Stats/index.cfm?search=Yes"
AquaferTable <- readHTMLTable(url, header=TRUE, which=1)
```

How do I do it? Anyone?

Comment: Error 500 when clicking on the link.

Comment: When I try to go to that URL i get an error page (error 500).

Comment: Once you search and pick what you want, there doesn't seem to be any nice url to put into R. I was able to manually copy the table, paste it into `read.table(text = "theTable", fill = T)` Where `theTable` is the text copied from the webpage with the header manually removed.